# QuickFixJ acceptor - upload orders in csv file

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I have an in-house developed application A (an initiator) that sends FIX orders to application B (an acceptor, also in-house) and receives the Execution report messages back. Users would like to upload orders in a csv file format to the acceptor B and the executions/rejects should flow back to application A for further processing. We are using QuikcFix/J on both sides and I have access to change codes/configs on both sides.

I could think of creating a stand-alone java process that could be a second Initiator, transform csv to a valid FIX message and send it off to the acceptor using the same TargetCompID/SenderCompID/BeginString as application A but I am not sure how I could ask the acceptor to send the replies back to the other initiator. Or I could just write a simple socket client that will send FIX message in binary format to the port exposed by the acceptor.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you,

Yoshiro

Comment: "using the same TargetCompID/SenderCompID/BeginString as application A". A FIX session can only have one counterparty.

Comment: The quickfix will not forward the messages automatically. You will need to create a new business logic to forward the messages from A to B as soon as you receive the messages from new C. C must use different sender/target configuration. You may add to your fromApp method some logic like: 
if ( session is from C ) forward to B;